# Passing an object from one Web Service to another Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

Services

1st Web Service - Integration Web Service 
    References SLInterface.dll (Object Model)
    References Shipping Web Service

//This service goes to different Systems and populates data into an object EntityShipment.  This EntityShipment object contains many properties of other object types.

//This service fills all of the data in the EntityShipment object that it can.

//We now want to pass this object to the Shipping Web Service.  When we try to do this, the code will not allow us to pass in this EntityShipment because the Shipping Web Services EntityShipment is a different name space and code thinks that it is not the same object type.

2nd Web Service Shipping Web Service
    References SLInterface.dll (Object Model)

```
Public EntityShipment Ship(EntityShipment objES)
{
    …..This does shipment processing based upon the address information etc that is passed in from the Integration Web Service.
    During this method more data is added to the EntityShipment object that we need to pass back to the Integration Web Service.
    Return objES;
}
```

What I want to do is pass the EntityShipment object from the integration service to the Shipping Service's Public Method.  We've tried using AutoMapper to Map the First services EntityShipment to the Second Services EntityShipment but we can't get it to work.  These services are designed this way as one is not dependent on the other.  This is the first time we're trying to make both of these services work together.

Comment: If both web services are using the EntityShipment class in the SLInterface.dll, the EntityShipment class should be in the same namespace for both. Unless I've misread your post.

Comment: From the First Web Service when I call the SecondWebService.Ship(<pass in entityObject here>) I get an error "Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'SmartLincInterface.EntityShipment' to 'ESInterface.ExpressShipper.EntityShipment'" if I create a new instance of entityshipment using the ESInterface.ExpressShipper.EntityShipment name space then it allows me to pass it in.
Service1 references Service2.  Service 2 is called ExpressShipper.

Comment: So they are two separate classes in different namespaces. You'll have to pick one as your transport object, use it on both sides to set up the data for transport, and convert between them where necessary. You have to pass the class that the receiving method requires to get the data from one web service to the other.